# ¿Como guardar un excel en vb6?

Tags: excel, vb6

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Tengo un método que realiza la exportación del excel pero el problema es al dar click al boton descargar abre excel con los datos de la consulta pero a la vez ya guardo el archivo en la ruta especificada.

Deseo que al dar click al descargar abra excel con los datos cargados de la consulta y al intentar cerrar recien realize la pregunta si deseas guardar el archivo si es **SI** lo guarde en una ruta que se especifique en el momento pero si es **NO** simplemente no se guarde.

Además de ello ese método `exportar_rs` deja ejecutando los excel guardados en segundo plano ya que intento borrarlos y no me deja.

Script

```
Private Sub exportar_rs(rs As Recordset)
On Error GoTo MensajeError

'--Cambiamos el icono del cursor(Modo Espera)
Me.MousePointer = vbHourglass

'--Creamos el objeto para trabajo con excel
Set Obj_Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'--Creamos el libro con el que trabajaremos - Este archivo debe existir
Dim nombreFile As String
Dim fecha As String
fecha = Format(Now, "ddMMyyyyHHmmss")
nombreFile = "\ReporteCita" + fecha + ".xlsx"
Set Obj_Libro = Obj_Excel.Workbooks.Add
Obj_Libro.SaveAs App.Path & nombreFile
'--Indicamos la hoja de excel
Set Obj_Hoja = Obj_Excel.ActiveSheet

'Llenar filas en excel
Obj_Hoja.Range("A2:B2").MergeCells = True
Obj_Hoja.Range("A2:B2").Font.Bold = True
Obj_Hoja.Range("A2:B2").WrapText = True
Obj_Hoja.Range("A2:B2").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Obj_Hoja.Range("A2:B2").Font.Color = vbWhite
Obj_Hoja.Range("A2:B2").Font.Size = 14
Obj_Hoja.Cells(2, 1) = "Reporte de Orden Cita Retiro"

Dim fila As Integer
fila = 3
rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF
    Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 1, 1) = "Nro Orden Retiro"
    Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 2, 1) = "Contenedor"
    Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 3, 1) = "Fecha Retiro"
    Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 4, 1) = "Hora Retiro"
    Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 5, 1) = "Placa"
    Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 6, 1) = "Chofer"
    Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 7, 1) = "Fecha Creacion"
    
    'Llenar los valores de la consulta
    Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 1, 2) = rs!CitaOrdenRetiro
    Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 2, 2) = rs!Contenedor
    If IsNull(rs!FechaRetiro) Then
        Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 3, 2) = ""
    Else
        Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 3, 2) = CDate(rs!FechaRetiro)
    End If
    
    Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 4, 2) = rs!HoraRetiro
    Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 5, 2) = rs!Placa
    Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 6, 2) = rs!Chofer
    If IsNull(rs!FechaCreacion) Then
        Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 7, 2) = ""
    Else
        Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 7, 2) = CDate(rs!FechaCreacion)
    End If
    
    fila = fila + 10
rs.MoveNext
Loop


Obj_Excel.Visible = True

'--Damos formato a la cabecera
With Obj_Hoja
    .Columns(1).Font.Bold = True 'Grosor de la fuente
    .Columns("A:B").AutoFit 'Auto ajustar la cabecera
    .Columns(2).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight 'Alinear valores a la izquierda
    .Range("A2:B2").Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'Pintar celda 3 = Rojo
End With

'--Eliminar las variables de objeto excel
Set Obj_Hoja = Nothing
Set Obj_Libro = Nothing
Set Obj_Excel = Nothing

'--Restaurar cursor
Me.MousePointer = vbDefault

Exit Sub
'--Controlar errores
MensajeError:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
On Error Resume Next

'--Destruir variables de excel
Set Obj_Hoja = Nothing
Set Obj_Libro = Nothing
Set Obj_Excel = Nothing
Me.MousePointer = vbDefault '--Devolver puntero

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba así:

```
Private Sub exportar_rs(rs As Recordset)
    On Error GoTo MensajeError
    
    '--Cambiamos el icono del cursor(Modo Espera)
    Me.MousePointer = vbHourglass
    
    '--Creamos el objeto para trabajo con excel
    Set Obj_Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    '--Creamos el libro con el que trabajaremos - Este archivo debe existir
    Dim nombreFile As String
    Dim fecha As String
    Dim pregunta As String
    
    fecha = Format(Now, "ddMMyyyyHHmmss")
    nombreFile = "\ReporteCita" + fecha + ".xlsx"
    Set Obj_Libro = Obj_Excel.Workbooks.Add
    'Obj_Libro.SaveAs App.Path & nombreFile
    '--Indicamos la hoja de excel
    Set Obj_Hoja = Obj_Excel.ActiveSheet
    
    'Llenar filas en excel
    Obj_Hoja.Range("A2:B2").MergeCells = True
    Obj_Hoja.Range("A2:B2").Font.Bold = True
    Obj_Hoja.Range("A2:B2").WrapText = True
    Obj_Hoja.Range("A2:B2").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Obj_Hoja.Range("A2:B2").Font.Color = vbWhite
    Obj_Hoja.Range("A2:B2").Font.Size = 14
    Obj_Hoja.Cells(2, 1) = "Reporte de Orden Cita Retiro"
    
    Dim fila As Integer
    fila = 3
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF
        Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 1, 1) = "Nro Orden Retiro"
        Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 2, 1) = "Contenedor"
        Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 3, 1) = "Fecha Retiro"
        Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 4, 1) = "Hora Retiro"
        Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 5, 1) = "Placa"
        Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 6, 1) = "Chofer"
        Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 7, 1) = "Fecha Creacion"
        
        'Llenar los valores de la consulta
        Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 1, 2) = rs!CitaOrdenRetiro
        Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 2, 2) = rs!Contenedor
        If IsNull(rs!FechaRetiro) Then
            Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 3, 2) = ""
        Else
            Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 3, 2) = CDate(rs!FechaRetiro)
        End If
        
        Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 4, 2) = rs!HoraRetiro
        Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 5, 2) = rs!Placa
        Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 6, 2) = rs!Chofer
        If IsNull(rs!FechaCreacion) Then
            Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 7, 2) = ""
        Else
            Obj_Hoja.Cells(fila + 7, 2) = CDate(rs!FechaCreacion)
        End If
        
        fila = fila + 10
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    
    Obj_Excel.Visible = True
    
    '--Damos formato a la cabecera
    With Obj_Hoja
        .Columns(1).Font.Bold = True 'Grosor de la fuente
        .Columns("A:B").AutoFit 'Auto ajustar la cabecera
        .Columns(2).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight 'Alinear valores a la izquierda
        .Range("A2:B2").Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'Pintar celda 3 = Rojo
    End With
    
    'Una vez terminas de dar formato al libro preguntamos si lo cerramos o si lo dejamos abierto
    pregunta = MsgBox("¿Deseas guardar y cerrar el libro o bien lo mantengo abierto?", vbYesNo, "Atención")
    
    'Si he respondido "SI" guardo el libro y lo cierro
    If pregunta = vbYes Then
        Obj_Libro.SaveAs App.Path & nombreFile
        Obj_Libro.Close savechanges:=False
    End If
    
    '--Eliminar las variables de objeto excel
    Set Obj_Hoja = Nothing
    Set Obj_Libro = Nothing
    Set Obj_Excel = Nothing
    
    '--Restaurar cursor
    Me.MousePointer = vbDefault
    
    Exit Sub
    '--Controlar errores
MensajeError:
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    On Error Resume Next
    
    '--Destruir variables de excel
    Set Obj_Hoja = Nothing
    Set Obj_Libro = Nothing
    Set Obj_Excel = Nothing
    Me.MousePointer = vbDefault '--Devolver puntero

End Sub
```

Comment: si quiero que la ruta donde se va a guardar la especifiquen.